# Display default data for list box using jquery

Tags: jquery, listbox

I have two list boxes, one for grade and another for subject. Upon change of grade the subjects are populated in the subject list. The values for both the lists are populated using ajax calls. Upon selection of subject the relevant syllabus is populated.

```
 <select id="gradeSelector">
   <option value=11 > 11</option>
   <option value=12 selected="selected"> 11</option>
 </select>

 <select name=subjects id=subjects>
   <option value=0 selected="selected"> Maths</option>
   <option value=1 >Science</option>
 </select>
```

My question is, on page load I would like to load default grade,subject and syllabus.

I tried doing this:

```
  $("#gradeSelector").load('change',function(){ /*the options are populated here*/});

  $("#subjects").load('change',function(){/* the options are populated here*/});
```

It helps display the syllabus of default subject and grade but I am unable to change the value of list box any further.

Could somebody throw some light please.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill default data in dropdown on page load as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gradeSelector").append($("<option></option>").val('select').html('select'));
});
```

Comment: @Patel - I have already set the default values for the two list boxes by doing - <option val="" selected=selected>test</option>.

Comment: Then whats problem tell me in brief.

Comment: @Patel - on page load i want grade 12 and subject Science to be displayed.